# REGEXP_EXTRACT () every word except ‘,’ in a field

Tags: regex, google-analytics, looker-studio, re2

I’d like to select country except ‘,’ from a data field which looks like this

```
Japan,Singapore,Italy,France
```

and my Code looks like this `REGEXP_EXTRACT(country,'([^,]*)')`, unfortunately, it works but only the country at the first was selected. How can I code it to select it all?

Comment: can you add global flag (`/g`) for the expression, I don't know how can I add it in data studio.

Comment: Thank you, I added /g but data studio return null in every data field. I am not sure REGEXP_EXTRACT in data studio support /g or not.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly changed the RegEx to `([^,]+)` to make the country name at least one digit. Using `*` creates empty matches so that every other match contains the country name. ([Example](https://regex101.com/r/vBamlE/2))

Take a look at the fixed example [here](https://regex101.com/r/vBamlE/1/).

Important is the `/g` tag in the end to make the RegEx match globally.

Comment: Thank you, I added /g but data studio return null in every data field. I am not sure REGEXP_EXTRACT  in data studio support /g or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to extract all the characters except `,` then it could be achieved using either of the the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below:

### 1) Replace `,` with   (space)

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(country, ",", " ")
```

### 2) Remove `,`

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(country, ",", "")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b105a7a1-a9d9-4987-a646-77a95f21bd30) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]